# The module "srmlib.dll" was loaded but the entry-point DllRegisterServer was not found

Tags: c#, dll, regsvr32

When I'm trying to run code that uses srmlib.dll I’m getting an exception, for not register the srmlib.dll, but when I'm trying to register it (regsvr32) I'm getting the above error.

I found an entry in my registry for that Dll: `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\Installer\Assemblies\C:|Program Files|Reference Assemblies|Microsoft|FSRM|v7.0|srmlib.dll`

I used Depends to check the Dll and saw that IESHIMS.dll is missing but I'm not sure that has anything to do with my problem.

What to do?

Answer (score 0):

It turns up that when loading the srmlib.dll it interacts with the server and therefore has to be on active FSRM server.

So what you need to do it quiet simple, just configure your server to run FSRM service as shown on this link: http://blogs.technet.com/b/josebda/archive/2008/08/20/the-basics-of-windows-server-2008-fsrm-file-server-resource-manager.aspx

and run the code on that server.
That should solve the problem.